# Google Map V2 having trouble to display

Tags: google-maps, button, click, fragment

Any idea what is wrong with my code?
I just want to display the map 
but the map having force close error, when I onclick a textview.
I've done the necessary thing at the XML layout, by adding

```
android:onClick="onClick"
android:clickable="true"
```

I've check the map.java, actually, it is working fine.
I've also check the onclick textview too, it is also working fine.
However, when I want to link both together, meaning show map.java upon onclick textview. However it gave me error.
Can someone advice me what is wrong with my code?
Thank you in advance.

the onclick textview code:
I've implements the onclicklistener

```
     @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
         //TODO Auto-generated method stub
    startActivity(new Intent(SingleMenuItemActivity.this,
                map.class));

}
```

map.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class map extends FragmentActivity {
    private GoogleMap map;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            map = fm.getMap(); 
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());

    }


}
```

map_shown.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<fragment
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:id="@+id/map"  
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

logcat error:

```
   08-13 01:54:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(4183): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 01:54:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(4183): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fambond/com.example.fambond.map}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-13 01:54:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(4183):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
08-13 01:54:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(4183):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
08-13 01:54:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(4183):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-13 01:54:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(4183):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
08-13 01:54:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(4183):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-13 01:54:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(4183):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-13 01:54:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(4183):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
08-13 01:54:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(4183):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 01:54:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(4183):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-13 01:54:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(4183):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
08-13 01:54:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(4183):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
08-13 01:54:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(4183):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-13 01:54:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(4183): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-13 01:54:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(4183):     at com.example.fambond.map.onCreate(map.java:18)
08-13 01:54:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(4183):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
08-13 01:54:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(4183):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
08-13 01:54:05.850: E/AndroidRuntime(4183):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably this line

```
 map = fm.getMap();
```

returns you null, and then you call something on null object -> exception